# C++ method returns pointer to abstract class, need to use a method from the subclass

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, abstract-class

so I'm writing a compiler in C++. Currently on the scanner portion.

The method declaration inside the scanner is

```
Token * Scanner::next_token()
{
  string * test = new string("Test");
  IdToken * testToken = new IdToken(test);
  return testToken;  
}
```

The IdToken class has a method get_attribute() that returns the value of the private variable attr (which in this case is a string, the one passed in on creation). Token (the abstract class) does not have this method.

Inside the main of my testing I have this:

```
IdToken * testToken = testScanner->next_token();
```

But g++ doesn't like that, and says that it's an invalid conversion from Token* to IdToken*.

I need to turn the token returned by the method into an IdToken in order to get the attribute, since when I try to directly call get_attribute() on the token returned it tells me that Token::get_attribute() does not exist.

Not sure entirely how to go about fixing this since my knowledge of C++ inheritance and such is struggling. I did all the research I could but I couldn't find anything that I both understood and solved my problem.

Here is Scanner.cc

```
Scanner::Scanner (char * filename)
{
  buf = new Buffer(filename);
}

//Destroy new things
Scanner::~Scanner()
{
  delete buf;
}

//The huge DFA turned into code
Token * Scanner::next_token()
{
  string * test = new string("Test");
  IdToken * testToken = new IdToken(test);
  return testToken;
}
```

And here is IdToken.cc

```
IdToken::IdToken() : Token()
{
  set_token_type (TOKEN_ID);
  attribute = new string("UNINITIALIZED IDENTIFIER ATTRIBUTE");
}

IdToken::IdToken (string *attr) : Token()
{
  set_token_type (TOKEN_ID);
  attribute = new string(*attr);
}

IdToken::~IdToken()
{  if (attribute != NULL) {
    delete attribute;
  }
}


string *IdToken::get_attribute() const
{
  string *attr = new string(*attribute);
  return attr;
}


void IdToken::set_attribute(string *attr)
{ 
  if (attribute != NULL) {
    delete attribute;
  }
  attribute = new string (*attr);
}


string *IdToken::to_string()
{
  string *attribute_name = new string ("ID:" + *attribute);
  return attribute_name;
}
```

And lastly token.cc

```
#include "token.h"

Token::Token()
{
  type = TOKEN_NO_TYPE;
}

Token::~Token()
{}

void Token::set_token_type (token_type_type type)
{
  this->type = type;
}

token_type_type Token::get_token_type() const
{
  return type;
}
```

It's not nearly done, I just need help with figuring out how to access get_attribute.

Comment: A humble suggestion since I worked with compilers... why don't you first study C++ and **afterwards** try to write a toy compiler? And for the question here posting IdToken and Token code could greatly help

Comment: I'll edit accordingly. It's for a class. I know C++ fairly well but I haven't dealt with anything to do with inheritance, and certainly not of this caliber before.

I'll edit the post and add the code.

Comment: I agree with Marco. However, it's not clear to me why you need to know at that point what kind of token it is. The answer is either to NOT care what kind of token it is at this point, or possibly using `dynamic_cast` (or `llvm::dyn_cast` if you are using `llvm` for the backend)

Comment: Additionally, in my compiler, I just have one `Token` class, that can return the `type` of the token (such as `Identifier`, `Integer`, `Plus`, etc).

Comment: I know what kind of token it is, and I can figure that out with the methods I have. What I can't figure out is how to access the get_attribute() method.

Comment: I added the code, there is one token class, which has a token type ( a number associated with if it's a keyword or an int or an id, etc). Then each type has its own class that holds an attribute and such.

Comment: You know NOW because it's hard-coded. The point is of course that when you are compiling (possibly incorrect) source-code that isn't hard coded in your source file, you won't know what token you get "next". In other words, you will still need to check that the token is the correct one.

Comment: I will though, as I can just have an if statement that checks what the type is on return.

Comment: Basically the TL;DR is that I know it's pointing to a certain type and can find that out using methods I already have. I just can't access get_attribute because that's in IdToken (and all other subclasses of Token except one) but not Token itself)

Comment: Adding a virtual function to Token or using dynamic_cast are the choices, as many others have already written. But also worth mentioning: next_token should probably return an IdToken*. I know there are various rules discouraging returning concrete types, but in this case, it's highly likely that the caller wants to use functionality that is only in IdToken, not Token. And, obviously, only IdTokens get returned. Maybe later more types of tokens might be returned, but in that case, there will need to be some sort of test by the caller for what type of token has been received.

Comment: The last part of your comment is correct: this function will return pointers to KeywordTokens and IdTokens and other such things, so it has to have the abstract class in the return.

I'll hold off on changing anything until I get a better understanding of how the inheritance is supposed to work in this case. Combining inheritance with pointers makes my head hurt.

Comment: Don't dynamically allocate std::string and pass around as a pointer.

Comment: "I know C++ fairly well but I haven't dealt with anything to do with inheritance" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input EJP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

1. Create a `virtual` member function in `Token`.

   ```
   virtual std::string get_attribute() const = 0;
   ```

   Implement appropriately for the sub-classes of `Token`. Use it as:

   ```
   Token * testToken = testScanner->next_token();
   std::string attr = testToken->get_attribute();
   ```
2. Use `dynamic_cast` to get an `IdToken*` from a `Token*`. If the cast is successful, call `get_attribute()`. on the `IdToken*`.

   ```
   Token * testToken = testScanner->next_token();
   IdToken * testIdToken = dynamic_cast<IdToken*>(testToken);
   if ( testIdToken )
   {
      std::string attr = testIdToken->get_attribute();
   }
   ```

Comment: Is dynamic casting good coding practice in this case? I've never used that before and I'm a tad confused. The pointer returned is a pointer to an IdToken object, but the compiler only sees it as a pointer to a Token.

Comment: @Neal use it if you have to, but working with base types is usually a better practice

Comment: Okay. I can ask my professor about it tomorrow but I figured looking around on the internet couldn't hurt. He is the one who gave us Scanner.h which has it declared as is in my Scanner.cc so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Use a virtual member function if it makes sense for your class hierarchy. If it doesn't, use of `dynamic_cast` is the next best option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look in to both options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dynamic_cast`

```
struct Token {
    virtual ~Token() {} 
};

struct IdToken : public Token {
    int getAttribute() {return 1;}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv} {

    Token* token = new IdToken();

    dynamic_cast<IdToken*>(token)->getAttribute();

    delete token;
}
```

Unfortunately, `dynamic_cast` tends to be rather slow and you would probably want to avoid frequent calls to it. It is safe, however. It returns a `nullptr` on failure. You could also use `reinterpret_cast`, which is faster, but isn't safe.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't make a class hierarchy for the tokens. There's a relatively small set of attributes and parameters, and you could, potentially, use a union to store them, if you really have to.

But if you MUST, then use `dynamic_cast` to call your `get_attribute`:

```
Token* token = testScanner->next_token()

IdToken *idToken = dynamic_cast<IdToken*>(token);
if(idToken)
{
   idToken->get_attribute();
}
```

Note that you do need the `if`, or your program will crash if the token you got wasn't an `IdToken` [or derived from an `IdToken`].

Oh, and `dynamic_cast` is not a trivial operation that takes no time at all. So avoiding it in preference for a base-class virtual function is nearly always better. My compiler uses a couple of dozen `llvm::dyn_cast`, for the AST that comes out of the parser, because doing a fully generic AST class that can cope with all the special cases of variable expressions, for-loops and function declarations in the same class would make a monster of a class with a few dozen virtual functions, most of which would require a single implementation for a single derived class, but a "null" value for most others - and most of the time I'd need to know what class it actually is anyway...

Here's my [Token class](https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/token.h) - I'm sure there are faults there too, I'm not a compiler expert, this is my third language I've worked on, and the first one to actually compile to machine code, and I'm cheating by using llvm as the backend.

Don't do `string *something = new string;` use an empty or "unknown" string to mean "not yet set"

Also don't use `if (pointer) delete pointer;` -  `delete` works just fine on pointers that are `NULL` - the redundant if is probably not removed by the compiler, since in a vanishingly small number of cases, the extra overhead of calling `delete` is worth saving - but not in a destructor. If you have an additional `if (pointer)` everywhere in a large project, it soon adds up to several thousand bytes of extra code - if the destructor then happens to be inlined, it's multiplied by the number of inlines it has, which could be quite a lot of useless code in your project. Compiler code tends to get large enough without useless bloat.